# How to establish p2p connection between two phones?

Tags: android

I just want to write an app for andorid which is very similar to facetime on iphone or skype's video. Just want to implement a P2P connection for video transmit and display. Is there somebody who has some related document or code about that. And one thing I want to know is how to establish a p2p connection between two phones? Just need the IP address to establish a tcp connection or I need some other information. And also if two phone are not in the same LAN or have firewall between them, how could I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, UDP is used for applications like P2P audio/video, not TCP.  UDP tolerates dropped packets where TCP does not.  For something similar to what you described, a protocol like SIP is used to negotiate the connection.  With SIP, I register my presence with a SIP registrar which is where I appear.  I might have a handle like user@my.cool.sip.example.com.  The SIP registrar is sitting on my.cool.sip.example.com and maintains a list of all attached users and their IP address.  Connection requests are proxied through the SIP registrar which knows how to contact the user.  Since all users of the registrar make an outgoing connection to their SIP registrar, no firewall punching is necessary to initially establish contact.  Another SIP client might have a name like user2@their.favorite.sip.example.com.  They will connect to their SIP registrar just like I connect to mine.  When they want to contact me, they will send a message to their registrar which then forwards it to my SIP registrar.  When I send a response back, I send it to my SIP registrar with a destination using their from address.  My SIP registrar contacts theirs who ultimately forwards it to the client.